# Does the state of the holographic bulk dual of a QFT depends upon more than just the wave function?

Tags: wavefunction, ads-cft, holographic-principle

Suppose we have two different QFTs with the same set of quantum fields which differ in their Lagrangians by a relevant operator. Assume both QFTs approach a CFT fixed point in the UV. Suppose at time $t=t_0$, both QFTs have the same wavefunction in the Schroedinger picture. According to the AdS/QFT conjecture, both QFTs would be dual to a theory of quantum gravity in one higher dimension. However, despite the fact that the QFT wavefunction is the same in both cases, the dual bulk state at $t_0$ will differ for both examples. So, does this mean the dual bulk state at $t_0$ depends upon more than just the QFT wavefunction at $t_0$?

I'm asking this because in AdS/MERA, the tensor network only depends upon the entanglement structure of the wave function and not the Hamiltonian.